# No visible @interface for 'SBJson4Parser' declares the selector 'objectWithString:error'

Tags: ios, sbjson

I've founded this error "**no visible @interface for 'SBJson4Parser' declares the selector 'objectWithString:error'**" when I've done importing "SBJson4.h" in my code. I don't know why I've founed this error.

```
SBJson4Parser *parser = [[SBJson4Parser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"Name"], [status objectForKey:@"LoginUrl"] );
}
```

Comment: You get the error because there is no such method on the `SBJson4Parser` class. Look at the docs. The class only has two instance methods and you don't use either of them.

Comment: Why don't you use `NSJSONSerialization` instead? It's part of the iOS SDK.

Comment: @rmaddy pls let me know how to declare? by the way, thanks for NSJSONSerialization. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

The interface completely changed in version 4. You need to read the docs when you upgrade major versions! That method doesn't exist in version 4. Stick with version 3.2.x if you want that, or upgrade to NSJSONSerialisation if you don't need streaming support.

Comment: what method should i declare here to resolve this error?

Comment: You cannot simply "declare a method to resolve this error". If you're upgrading from version <4 to 4+ you _have_ to make changes to your code. A Major Version change means this version has a _different interface_ than the previous. See http://semver.org for more info on version numbering :-)